# change the name of the XML node

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

How do I change from `<forward></forward>` to `<backward></backward>` without delete in actionscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution to your problem:

```
var xml = <forward><item>item string</item></forward>;

var xmlString:String = xml.toXMLString();
xmlString = xmlString.split("<forward>").join("<backward>");
xmlString = xmlString.split("</forward>").join("</backward>");

var xml2 = new XML(xmlString);
trace(xml2.item);
```

I tested it and it seems like working.

Rob

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to change it using [setName](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/XML.html#setName()):

```
var xml:XML = <forward />;
xml.setName('backward');
trace(xml.toXMLString());//prints: <backward/>
```

Comment: This is the correct solution, you just need to loop through all instances of "forward"

Comment: Yeah, George's solution is more valid indeed.